# How could the contextual filter "Content: Nid" return the TNID instead of NID?

Tags: 7, views

I am using the contextual filter "Content: Nid" in Views3, and I want it returns the TNID instead of the NID *When the filter value is NOT available*.

I tried the following code.

```
$node = node_load($argument);
$argument = $node->tnid;
return $argument;
```

I also tried the following code.

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$argument = $node->tnid; // bzw. $argument(1) = $node->tnid;
return $argument;
```

I used that code in *Provide default value:PHP Code* Field, but nothing worked.

---

I solved the problem by adding this code to the page.tpl.php.

```
$imagemenuview = views_get_view('projectimagemenu');
echo $imagemenuview->preview('block', array($node->tnid));
```

I am still interested in the solution using the contextual filter "Content: Nid" returning the TNID instead of the NID *When the filter value is NOT available*.

Comment: There is an argument “Content translation: Translation set node ID” when core *Content translation* module is enabled. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP code should work:

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
return (isset($node->tnid) ? $node->tnid : $node->nid);
```

The better way (without *evil eval()*) is to provide own plugun of type `'argument default'` which will do work. Look at [`Content ID from URL`](http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/blob/423bc82111925528f00838bd200220663319c293:/modules/node.views.inc#l658) argument default plugin as an example.